# How to render partial view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I have the following:

> /controllers/test_controller.rb
>
> /views/test/index.html.erb
>
> /views/test/_partial.html.erb

I want to render the partial in the index view.  I'm doing this:

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Test#index</h1>
<%= render "_partial" %>
```

_partial.html.erb

```
<p>This is partial content</p>
```

When I go to localhost:3000/test/index, I get this error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Test#index
Missing partial /__partial with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
Extracted source (around line #2):

1 <h1>Test#index</h1>
2 <%= render "_partial" %>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try following <%= render "partial" %>

Comment: @Shani: Thanks.  That works.  So the file should still have an underscore but when referencing, don't use the underscore?

Comment: correct 

partials are named with a leading underscore to distinguish them from regular views, even though they are referred to without the underscore. This holds true even when you're pulling in a partial from another folder:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has already been answered, but when the partial is in the same directory as your current view, you can just render the partial with no underscore. But if you want to extract a partial from another controller you will need to take it one step back and use a more complete path, like `"users/partial"`.

Answer (score 2):

All depends where is your partial. If you have the partial `_partial` in layouts folder, you only have to do is call the partial like this `<%= render "partial" %>`.

Rails know that a file with the underscore at the beggining is a partial. So, when you render the partial, you don't have to use the underscore.

Remember, Rails is convention over configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
        <%= render 'erb_partials/post', user: user %>
    <% end %>
```